# R Mapping Makes Messy, Ungrouped Borders, but only when data frame is merged with shape data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to map some spatial data, and I'm getting a weird result that I haven't seen asked and answered before.

I pull in the shape data like so (with intermediate steps to match precinct IDs to the ObjectIDs elided):

```
shp<-readOGR('./2016 precincts', '2016_Precincts')
shp<-spTransform(shp, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
shp<-tidy(shp)
```

When I do the following:

```
ggmap(map)+geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group), size=.1, color=borderColor, data=testShp, alpha=0.5)
```

I get a nice, blank map of the precincts. However, once I merge in any data and try to fill in the precincts, like this:

```
shp<-merge(shp, precinctTotals, by.x='vtds', by.y='precinct',all.x=T)
```

the border lines stop drawing correctly. I can't figure out why. It appears that the only thing that changes is that there is additional data in the data frame. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Could you provide examples (The '2016_Precincts' shapefile and the precinctTotals)?

Comment: I think this is because `base::merge` can/does change the order of entries. Try using `dplyr::left_join`, or merging your data to the `shp@data` slot of the polygons. Or, arranging the output of your merge by the "order" variable.

Comment: Thanks, @TaylorH. It's a bit surprising that the sort isn't handled in-function. But sorting by order works for me.